# Error using JQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



    jQuery.validator.addMethod("val_address", function(value, element) {
        return  (value == 'Address only here...');
    }, "Address must be set to a value other than default...");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("val_city", function(value, element) {
        return (value == 'City only here...');
    }, "City must be set to a value other than default...");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("val_zip", function(value, element) {
        return (value == 'Zip only here...');
    }, "Zip must be set to a value other than default...");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("val_state", function(value, element) {
        return (value == 'State only here...');
    }, "State must be set to a value other than default...");

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function () { alert("submitted!"); }
    });


    var ruleSetaddress = {
        val_address : true,
        required: true    
    };

    var ruleSetcity = {
        val_city : true,
        required: true
    };

    var ruleSetstate = {
        val_state : true,
        required: true
    };

    var ruleSetzip = {
        val_zip : true,
        required: true
    };

    $("#advanced-searchform").validate({
        rules: {                            
            search_address: ruleSetaddress,
            search_city: ruleSetcity,
            search_state: ruleSetstate,
            search_zip: ruleSetzip     
        },  
        errorElement: "span" ,                              
        messages: {
            search_address: " Enter Address",
            search_city: " Enter City",
            search_state: " Enter State",
            search_zip: " Enter Zip",

        }
    });
    $("#searchform").validate({
        rules: {                            
            search_address: ruleSetaddress,
            search_city: ruleSetcity,
            search_state: ruleSetstate,
            search_zip: ruleSetzip     
        },  
        errorElement: "span" ,                              
        messages: {
            search_address: " Enter Address",
            search_city: " Enter City",
            search_state: " Enter State",
            search_zip: " Enter Zip",
        }
    });

}
```

You can see the form here--> http://dimitri.clientdemos.pw/

For some reason, nothing is happening- the values obtained using PHP code are basically shown as the default values. So the rules are to check if the default values are being submitted unchanged (which should not be done) and to check if blank values are being sent(again this should not be done).

What is wrong with above code?

UPDATE I can see an alert message now- when I put a random alert message- but how do I know where to show the error message? How do I define such an element? In my code above

```
 errorElement: "span" ,
```

What is span here? Is it the ID of a text box/span element? How do I define such an error element?

Comment: At first glance, there appears to be nothing wrong with your code... then again, I cannot see your HTML or PHP.  What does basic troubleshooting reveal?  Are the PHP echos showing the correct values within the _rendered_ HTML code?  If not, then your problem is not within the JavaScript code.

Comment: @Sparky the PHP Echos are showing the correct values within rendered HTML code-- the same echos are used to fill the default values in the resp. HTML boxes in the form itself- when the form is opened- I have simply copied the relevant PHP echos from there to the JS code above.

Comment: If you're 100% positive that your PHP is operating as intended, then only show us the code as rendered in the browser including the HTML for the form.

Comment: @Sparky the updated code is shown now-also you can see the form for yourself at the URL given in post

Comment: @Arvind: Your call to `.validate` is not inside a `$(document).ready(...)` event handler. The form doesn't exist on the page when you initialize the validation on it.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker  I can see a alert message now after making the change suggested by you- just one thing- how do I define the tag where error messages are to be shown? I am referring to errorElement: "span"-- doe s this span refer to the ID/name of an HTML element? What is that element? Thanks